# What are the possible things that we can do using tor browser that we cannot do with other browsers?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I heard that tor browser uses the anonymous feature while browsing. I need to know about it in detail. What is tor or why it is used. I searched for this in the internet but few blogs scares me. So what can I do with Tor Browser what I can't do with other browsers?

Comment: Your question is quite broad. Basically a correct answer would be *everything*. So maybe think about what use cases you have in mind and ask specific questions about your use case. Also the website of the Tor Project might be helpful: https://www.torproject.org/about/torusers.html.en

Comment: thank you, my question is what we can do using tor browser that other browsers cannot do. just simple it is

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser is just a normal browser. It is a Mozilla Firefox which has some additional improvements regarding your privacy. Besides Firefox there is the Tor software itself which routes your Internet connection through different hops around the world.

So when you use Tor Browser you can do basically the same things as with any other browser. The difference is that Tor Browser tries very hard to keep your location (ip address) hidden and thus provide anonymity. Furthermore the Tor Browser also tries to close several vulnerabilities which decrease your privacy on the net.

Comment: upvoted, great response Jens. I have an inquiry regarding Tor myself. If you happen to know the answer I would love your feedback https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14650/turning-off-the-proxy-part-of-tor

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser is split into tor parts, the browser and Tor itself.

Let's look at Tor first, it routes the traffic through multiple hops (different hosts on the Internet) to make it harder for anyone to figure out who you are or where you are.

Now, let's looks at the browser part. Tor Browser is based on Firefox with a few yet important changes. Here is a list with the main differences:

- Tor Browser ensures you get a different circuit for every domain. (e.g. google.com does not take the same route through tor as example.net)
- Cookies, caches, etc. are separated by domain. (If you have an Google advert on example.net and somewhere.else Google won't be able to make the correlation.)
- Tor Browser disables certain features known to be prone to security issues. (The security slider allows you to disable even more such features.)
- Tor Browser is binary reproducible (It is possible to prove that Tor Browser was build from a particular source.)
- Tor Browser has measurements to make sure that traffic is routed via Tor. (Not the case with all browsers.)
- Tor Browser avoids writing any information to disk (history, cache, etc.). (If anyone gets access do your machine, there is no browsing history.)

For a more complete list take a look at [The Design and Implementation of the Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/).